# Put in one row with same id

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, left-join

I have problem.
My sql give me 2 rows. 
Row 1,2,3,4,5 are the same. 
Rest is diffrent. 
I would like to make it in one row if first 5 rows are the same.

```
declare @data date ='2016-01-22'
declare @typdnia char = ''
declare @strefa varchar(15) = ''
declare @opis varchar(30) = ''
select * from 

(
select  Emp_IntColumn1 Kod, 
        Emp_Surname Nazwisko, 
        Emp_FirstName Imie, 
        isnull(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Doc_DocumentDate, 120),'') Data,
        @typdnia TypDnia,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),elm_datecolumn1,108) GodzOd,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),elm_datecolumn2,108) GodzDo,
        @strefa Strefa,
        @opis Opis,
        ELM_ShortStringColumn6 Wydzial,
        ELM_ShortStringColumn5 Wydzial_adres_wezla,
        isnull(a.dic_svalue,' brak') Projekt,
        isnull(b.DIC_ShortStringColumn1,'') Projekt_adres_wezla

from Employees
 join elements on emp_id=ELM_EmpID and ELM_FflID=200 
 join documents on elm_objectid=doc_id and Doc_DdfID=2 and Doc_DocumentDate=@data
 left join dictionaries a on ELM_IntColumn2=a.DIC_ID
 left join Dictionaries b on elm_intcolumn2=b.DIC_ID
 ) dane
```

Comment: "My sql give me 2 rows. Row 1,2,3,4,5 are the same."??? How can row 1 to 5 be the same if you only have two rows?

Comment: Let me suggest changing the title of your question to sth like 'Failed to eliminate duplicate rows from query result even when using DISTINCT' and providing more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

Comment: Did you mean 'Of course, that I tried before'? If so, well great then, but please post your own answer so we can see your solution.

Comment: tfu sory i mean that is not working :P, stupid autocorrection

Comment: The resulting rows 1 to 5 are exactly the same in every column and `SELECT DISTINCT` doesn't eliminate that. Very interesting - could you please post the output?